# Bootstrap datetimepicker disable days before today and weekends

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, datetimepicker

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
    });
    $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

I'm using bootstrap datetimepicker. How do I disable weekends, public holidays and all past days before today with datetimepicker? I can't seem to find any documentation or solutions and I have no idea how to do it as well. My public holidays are in an array.

Comment: do you need two datetime pickers ?

Comment: @IamRaviteja Yeah! Because I want users to select the start timing and end timing

Comment: have you checked my code ?

Comment: @IamRaviteja yes I did! Thank you for your help :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.

**HTML**

```
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>Datetimepicker</h6>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
     var date = new Date();
            var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
            var currentDate = date.getDate();
            var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({  minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2015"),
                    moment("12/24/2015")
                    ]});

        });
```

Include the public holidays in `moment`as shown.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/5u694sat/2/)